Meaning of Timestamp Retrieved by AudioQueueGetCurrentTime() in AudioQueue Callback
I'm working on an audio project and have a question regarding the meaning of the timestamp retrieved by AudioQueueGetCurrentTime().
According to the Apple Developer Documentation, the following calculation gives the audio time being played (since AudioQueueStart):
- (Float64) GetCurrentTime {
    AudioTimeStamp c;       
    AudioQueueGetCurrentTime(playState.queue, NULL, &c, NULL);  
    return c.mSampleTime / _av->audio.sample_rate;
}

However, in a project I'm working on, I noticed the following code inside the fillAudioBuffer callback function of AudioQueue:

static void fillAudioBuffer(AudioQueueRef queue, AudioQueueBufferRef buffer){
    
    int lengthCopied = INT32_MAX;
    int dts= 0;
    int isDone = 0;

    buffer->mAudioDataByteSize = 0;
    buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount = 0;
    
    OSStatus err = 0;
    AudioTimeStamp bufferStartTime;

    AudioQueueGetCurrentTime(queue, NULL, &bufferStartTime, NULL);
    

    
    while(buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount < numPacketsToRead && lengthCopied > 0){
        if (buffer->mAudioDataByteSize) {
            break;
        }
        
        lengthCopied = getNextAudio(_av,buffer->mAudioDataBytesCapacity-buffer->mAudioDataByteSize, (uint8_t*)buffer->mAudioData+buffer->mAudioDataByteSize,&dts,&isDone);
        if(!lengthCopied || isDone) break;
      
        if(aqStartDts < 0) aqStartDts = dts;
        if (dts>0) currentDts = dts;
        if(buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount ==0){
            bufferStartTime.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
            bufferStartTime.mSampleTime = (Float64)(dts-aqStartDts) * _av->audio.frame_size;
            
            if (bufferStartTime.mSampleTime <0 ) bufferStartTime.mSampleTime = 0;
            PMSG2("AQHandler.m fillAudioBuffer: DTS for %x: %lf time base: %lf StartDTS: %d\n", (unsigned int)buffer, bufferStartTime.mSampleTime, _av->audio.time_base, aqStartDts);
            
        }
        buffer->mPacketDescriptions[buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount].mStartOffset = buffer->mAudioDataByteSize;
        buffer->mPacketDescriptions[buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount].mDataByteSize = lengthCopied;
        buffer->mPacketDescriptions[buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount].mVariableFramesInPacket = _av->audio.frame_size;
        
        buffer->mPacketDescriptionCount++;
        buffer->mAudioDataByteSize += lengthCopied;
        
    }
    
#ifdef DEBUG
    int audioBufferCount, audioBufferTotal,  videoBufferCount, videoBufferTotal;
    bufferCheck(_av,&videoBufferCount, &videoBufferTotal, &audioBufferCount, &audioBufferTotal);
    
    PMSG2("AQHandler.m fillAudioBuffer: Video Buffer: %d/%d Audio Buffer: %d/%d\n", videoBufferCount, videoBufferTotal, audioBufferCount, audioBufferTotal);
    
    PMSG2("AQHandler.m fillAudioBuffer: Bytes copied for buffer 0x%x: %d\n",(unsigned int)buffer, (int)buffer->mAudioDataByteSize );
#endif  
    if(buffer->mAudioDataByteSize){
        
        if(err=AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters(queue, buffer, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 0, NULL, &bufferStartTime, NULL))
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            char sErr[10];

            PMSG2(@"AQHandler.m fillAudioBuffer: Could not enqueue buffer 0x%x: %d %s.", buffer, err, FormatError(sErr, err));
#endif
        }
    }

}

Based on the documentation for AudioQueueEnqueueBufferWithParameters and the variable naming used by the author, bufferStartTime seems to represent the time when the newly filled audio buffer will start playing, i.e., the time when all current audio in the queue has finished playing and the new audio starts. This interpretation suggests bufferStartTime is not the same as the time of the audio currently being played.
I have browsed through many related questions, but I still have some doubts.. I'm currently fixing an audio-video synchronization issue in my project, and there isn't much detailed information in the Apple Developer Documentation (or maybe my search skills are lacking).
Can someone clarify the exact meaning of the timestamp returned by AudioQueueGetCurrentTime() in this context? Is it the time when the current audio will finish playing, or is it the time when the new audio will start playing? Any additional resources or documentation that explain this in detail would also be appreciated.

That code you're wondering about doesn't actually use the time returned by AudioQueueGetCurrentTime(), although it does sometimes overwrite and then log the result.
I interpret this doco as meaning that AudioQueueGetCurrentTime should return the number of samples that the AudioQueue has output (or captured if you're using the input variant) or if that amount is negative, the number of samples in the future that the queue is scheduled to start in (and indeed AudioQueueStart() does have an optional start time, so that's reassuringly consistent).
The negative timestamp shenanigans lead me to believe that this is not the number of your samples actually consumed by the AudioQueue, but that's ok, because you already know how many samples you've supplied it (probably dts-aqStartDts in your code).
